# azcopy 8.1 always upload image with wrong content type application/octet-stream

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I am using azcopy 8.1 to upload .jpg files to azure blob storage but on upload the content type is set to **application/octet-stream** instead of **image/jpeg**.

Should it not recognized it from AzCopyConfig.json. Is this a bug?

```
& $azcopyLocation /Source:$sourcePath /Dest:$deploymentPath /destkey:$destinationKey /Pattern:"*.jpg" /S /Y
```

Answer (score 1):

See [/SetContentType:"content-type"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#setcontenttypecontent-type).

> AzCopy sets the content type for a blob or file to application/octet-stream by default. You can set the content type for all blobs or files by explicitly specifying a value for this option.
>
> If you specify this option without a value, then AzCopy sets each blob or file's content type according to its file extension.

So simply append `/SetContentType` to the command should work.

Comment: yes this works but I have a folder which contains .jpg .png .js .css (multiple file formats ). which I need to upload to storage having to handle each format separately is cumbersome. Then what is the purpose of AzCopyConfig.json

Comment: @kumar Hmm... See `If you specify this option without a value, then AzCopy sets each blob or file's content type according to its file extension.` Instead of `/SetContentType:image/jpg`, use `/SetContentType` will make AzCopy set content type according to file extension(based on `AzCopyConfig.json`). Is this what you want?

Comment: @kumar Feel free to ask if you have further questions, or if everything works could you accept the answer for others to refer?